# how to pass data from bootstrap form to mockemployeerepo in asp .net core razor pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, parameter-passing, razor-pages

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label asp-for="EmployeeEditProperty.Name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input asp-for="EmployeeEditProperty.Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label asp-for="EmployeeEditProperty.Email" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input asp-for="EmployeeEditProperty.Email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
</div>
```

Data not passing to

Employee employee= _EmployeeList.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID == UpdatedEmployee.ID);

```
        if(employee !=null)
        {
            employee.Name = UpdatedEmployee.Name;
            employee.Email = UpdatedEmployee.Email;
            employee.Department = UpdatedEmployee.Department;
        }
```

Comment: How did you post the data and how did you get the posted data? Your code can not help us reproduce your error, show more details please.

Comment: <form method="post" class="mt-3" >  
    <input hidden asp-for="empeditprop.ID" />
 
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="empeditprop.Name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input asp-for="empeditprop.Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
 This is bootstrap form ...

Comment: From here I dont get data to Mock Employee Repository class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties in view should match the property name in your post action,

You can check my demo:

```
<form method="post">
<div class="form-group row">
    <input hidden asp-for="EmployeeEditProperty.ID" value="1" />
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label asp-for="EmployeeEditProperty.Name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input asp-for="EmployeeEditProperty.Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
</div>
//....
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

The property names EmployeeEditProperty, so in post method, it should be EmployeeEditProperty too:

```
public ******(Employee EmployeeEditProperty)
```

Result:

[image]

Model Binding in razor pages, you can check [this article](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding)